# APScheduler Runs Too Early with Jitter

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler, jitter

I have a script that runs a function `WOL()` on Friday's at 8:05AM with a Jitter of 15 minutes.

My code is:

```
def WOL():
    response.post("https://example.com/WOL.php")

PC = sched.add_job(WOL, 'cron', hour=8, minute=5, jitter=900, day_of_week='fri')
sched.start()

print(PC.next_run_time) # Returns 2024-02-02 07:56:38.273177-08:00
```

According to the man-page for [apscheduler.triggers.cron](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html), `jitter` will "delay the job execution by jitter seconds at most".

If I set a start time of 8:05AM with jitter of 15min, why would it be trigerred 10minutes before it is supposed to run?